# Problem using algorithmicx, hyperef, and tex4ht together after updating MikTex

Tags: hyperref, miktex, tex4ht, algorithmicx

I have some documents using both algorithmicx and hyperref, which were handled correctly by htlatex in the past. When I updated my MikTex installation, generation of HTML started giving me errors. I have managed to cut down the problem to the following example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Some Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{Foo}{$A$}
  \ForAll{$a \in A$}
    \State process $a$
  \EndFor
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

When I run

```
make4ht TestAlgorithmicxWithTex4ht.tex
```

I get the following errors:

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: TestAlgorithmicxWithTex4ht.tex
[WARNING] tocid: char-def module not found
[WARNING] tocid: cannot fix section id's
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.4) (preloaded format=latex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    855      Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    12       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    13       TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

If I comment out the line with `\usepackage{hyperref}`, then `make4ht` completes successfully. PDF generation works OK in both cases, so the problem seems to be TeX4ht-specific.

Here are some package dates taken from MikTex console:
| Package              | Date      |
|----------------------|-----------|
| algorithmics         |  5/4/2005 |
| hyperref             | 2/23/2023 |
| miktex-*-bin-x64-2.9 | 4/15/2023 |
| make4ht              | 3/17/2023 |
| tex4ht               | 3/12/2022 |

Not sure if some other version info can be relevant and where to take it from.

Comment: the tex4ht.sty in miktex looks quite outdated, I have version 2021-09-14-14:11 there. In texlive it is much newer (and there compilation works).